# Azure - Faces does not return age?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying out the azure image analysis api.  I have the code below.  I thought that as a part of the Face analysis, I would get an estimated age back.  Everything that I send to it seems to return an age of 0.  Is this something I am going wrong?  Any ideas on this?  TIA.

```
ComputerVisionClient client =
  new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(azureImageKey)) { Endpoint = endPoint };
List<VisualFeatureTypes?> features = new List<VisualFeatureTypes?>()
{
    VisualFeatureTypes.Tags,
    VisualFeatureTypes.ImageType,
    VisualFeatureTypes.Faces,
    VisualFeatureTypes.Adult,
    VisualFeatureTypes.Brands,
    VisualFeatureTypes.Description
};
ImageAnalysis results = await client.AnalyzeImageAsync(img, visualFeatures: features);
```

Comment: @DasariKamali  thanks for your suggestion.  I'm handing some very high quality images in, so I don't think that is my problem.  I'm sending them via a stream, so I just let the image processor handle them and don't send a url.

Comment: Is there something in the options that I need to hand in besides .Faces?

Comment: I'm curious regarding this logging @DasariKamali.  How do I find out more about that?

Comment: I got the age with the stream code also. See in this [output](https://i.imgur.com/5o2xZq2.png).
 If possible, can you share your complete code can check it once?

Comment: Or, can I share my code with Stream and with the image URL in the answer? You can check.

Comment: @DasariKamali  My code is above.  I've tried this with a stream as well as an image in azure blob storage and just passing the url  neither option return anything to me.
Please share your code and let me see if there is something that I am not doing correct.

Comment: another thought that I have is that the account type that I am using does not allow for age.  Is there anything regarding the faces api that only returns ages if the account used is a paying account?  Right now, I am just trying things out so I am using the freebie account.

Comment: apologies as I have been rather busy with some other things.

Answer (score 0):

*I tried the following code with a stream in your code to obtain a person's age from an image URL in Azure Blob Storage.*

**Code :**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision.Models;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string azureImageKey = "<ComputerVision_key>";
        string endPoint = "<ComputerVision_endpoint>";

        ComputerVisionClient client = new ComputerVisionClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(azureImageKey)) { Endpoint = endPoint };

        string blobImageUrl = "https://<storage_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/<image_name>.jpg"; //make sure the blob have the public read access
        Stream imageStream = await DownloadImageFromBlobUrlAsync(blobImageUrl);

        List<VisualFeatureTypes?> features = new List<VisualFeatureTypes?>()
        {
            VisualFeatureTypes.Tags,
            VisualFeatureTypes.ImageType,
            VisualFeatureTypes.Faces,
            VisualFeatureTypes.Adult,
            VisualFeatureTypes.Brands,
            VisualFeatureTypes.Description
        };

        try
        {
            ImageAnalysis results = await client.AnalyzeImageInStreamAsync(imageStream, visualFeatures: features);

            Console.WriteLine("Image Analysis Results:");
            Console.WriteLine("\nTags:");
            foreach (var tag in results.Tags)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{tag.Name} ({tag.Confidence * 100}%)");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nDetected Faces:");
            foreach (var face in results.Faces)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Age: {face.Age}, Gender: {face.Gender}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    private static async Task<Stream> DownloadImageFromBlobUrlAsync(string blobImageUrl)
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(blobImageUrl);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Stream imageStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                return imageStream;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception($"Failed to download image from the storage blob URL. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

The program ran successfully, providing the accurate age and gender of the person in the blob URL, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: thank you.  I guess I am doing something wrong and will try it out.  Thank you again.  :-)